# How to upload an audio file with html and php?

Tags: php, html, file, audio, upload

I am struggling with creating an audio file upload form for my website. I feel like the upload section works properly, but when I try it out and I submit the uploading it goes to the right php page, but the screen is all white with nothing on it.

My goal is to move the uploaded audio file into the uploads directory on my server.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="gettfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
  <p> testen </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the php page:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = 'uploads';

$tmp_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"][$key];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
$_FILES['userfile']['error']

?>
```

Please note that I am a complete newbie with programming, so a really simple explanation would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove all `[$key]` you're not uploading multiples, you didn't even use/assign that key value. check for errors also and make sure that folder is writeable

Comment: and we is outta here

Comment: Whats thsi doing hanging there `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` its a good idea to check that but not to just throw it in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

//whats with $key. I dont see the need for that. try the code below. And the white screen? always print some message for your test code.
$uploads_dir = 'uploads';

```
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
    $moved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    if($moved && file_exists("$uploads_dir/$name")){
        echo 'file uploaded successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'].' -- ailed to move file';
    }
```

For the second issue you are facing, 
You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but I get this printed now:
Warning: Wrong parameter count for file_exists() in /home/a9447837/public_html/gettfile.php on line 7


-- ailed to move file

Comment: Sorry, I missed it earlier. Have updated that. Just to recheck if the moved file exists there or not.

Is that an error with updated file_exists() parameter?

Comment: Please check that the directory is writable, i.e. it has sufficient permissions that php can move files to that directory

Comment: Wow, that works great! But now I have one more problem. I tried it with a 200 kb audio file and that worked out great. But when I try it with a full song of 6 mb it says: Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/gettfile.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Comment: There may be two possibilities. If you are working on your system, try increasing the upload size limit. If you are on shared hosting, contact the service provider to get the size/capoacity increased.

Comment: You can see, I have updated in my answer above what you should do to fix this. Happy learning, happy coding.

Comment: I tried to create a file called php.ini with upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M in it and just put it in the public_html directory just like the index.html and the gettfile.php files. Is that the right way, because I still get the same error...

Comment: NO that is not. ok can you post the php info? create a php file with below content.

<?php

phpinfo();
?>
can  you provide output of this file ?

Comment: What part do you need of it? It is an incredibly long page and I cant post all of that output.

Comment: @Aditya I think I found the info you need. I put it as an answer to this question as it were too many characters.

Comment: Ok wait. Let me check.

Comment: Hi Bran you got that right. The file size allowed is only 2MB. Can you contact your service provider to get it increased?

Comment: You will also need to get max_post_size increased as per your requirement. The largest file size you want to allow should be set to both the values

Comment: Ah okay, I will contact my service provider for that. Thanks a lot for all your time and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is for @aditya**

```
PHP Core

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  On  On
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    /usr/lib/php/foot.php   /usr/lib/php/foot.php
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   /usr/lib/php/head.php   /usr/lib/php/head.php
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   system, show_source, exec, shell_exec, proc_open, passthru, set_time_limit, ini_restore, mysql_list_dbs, ini_alter, dl, pfsockopen, openlog, syslog, symlink, link, chgrp, leak, popen, escapeshellcmd, apache_child_terminate, apache_get_modules, apache_get_version, apache_getenv, apache_note, apache_setenv, virtual, mb_send_mail    system, show_source, exec, shell_exec, proc_open, passthru, set_time_limit, ini_restore, mysql_list_dbs, ini_alter, dl, pfsockopen, openlog, syslog, symlink, link, chgrp, leak, popen, escapeshellcmd, apache_child_terminate, apache_get_modules, apache_get_version, apache_getenv, apache_note, apache_setenv, virtual, mb_send_mail
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
error_append_string <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>   <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
error_log   error_log   error_log
error_prepend_string    <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table>  <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table>
error_reporting 6135    6135
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613    /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  On  On
ignore_repeated_source  On  On
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php   .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
log_errors  Off Off
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
max_execution_time  10  10
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  10  10
memory_limit    64M 64M
open_basedir    /home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp    no value
output_buffering    1   1
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   2M  2M
precision   12  12
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/local/bin/phpsendmail  /usr/local/bin/phpsendmail
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  /tmp    /tmp
user_dir    no value    no value
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
```